# How to group results based on time interval in mysql

Tags: mysql

I was assigned to develop a simple hit counter. My table is as following-

```
  ID | userID |     IP    | entityType| entityID |        date
-----+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------------
  1  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:02:12
  2  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:02:30
  3  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:02:42
  4  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:02:48
  5  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:02:56
  6  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:03:03
  7  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:03:21
  8  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:03:31
  9  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:03:38
 10  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:03:44
 11  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:04:01
 12  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:04:13
 13  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:04:30
 14  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:04:37
 15  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:04:56
 16  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:05:10
 17  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:05:18
 18  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:05:41
 18  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:05:56
 19  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:06:15
 20  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:06:26
 21  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:06:43
 22  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:06:58
 23  |    1   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:07:21
```

My problem is I need to group results based on time interval. This interval will be defined later by project manager which could vary from 1 minute to 30 minutes. The idea behind is if a specific user visits certain page (entity) with certain ID (entity ID) multiple times within the time interval defined all those hits will be counted as a single hit. There will be a cronjob running in this time interval to accumulate and then store in a different table.

I can't figure out how should I approach. I really look forward to have some guides.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Since my question is marked as exact duplicate of a certain question by so many users that I feel guilty for not explaining my problem enough.

Int the question regarding which my question is marked exact duplicate, the expected result is the count over time interval. But my problem is different than this. I need a solution by with I can count only one within a time interval. Please consider the following table-

```
  ID | userID |     IP    | entityType| entityID |        date
-----+--------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------------
  1  |    4   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:02:12
  2  |    4   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:02:30
  3  |    4   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:02:42
  4  |    4   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:03:08
  5  |    4   | 127.0.0.1 |    book   |   18     | 2017-01-27 10:03:27
```

Assume my expected time interval is defined `1 minute`. Please notice in the example `userID` `4` visited the same `entityID` `18` 4 times within `1 minute` time interval `(2017-01-27 10:02:12 - 2017-01-27 10:03:11)`. In this case the hit should be counted as 1. So that just `COUNT(*)` is not sufficient to achieve my result. I think I need to use mysql rank function to solve it. But cant figure out how.

I've updated my sample dataset to depict a specific case. Lets assume my time interval threshold is 1 minute. From my raw data I want the result as following-

```
entityType| entityID | count
----------+----------+-------
   book   | 18       |  5
```

Since the first hit entry for `entity` `book` with `entityID` `18` is `2017-01-27 10:02:12` so that the time intervals should be considered as `2017-01-27 10:02:12 to 2017-01-27 10:03:11`. After this interval next entry for the same `userID`, `entity` and `entityID` is `2017-01-27 10:03:21` so that the time interval should be `2017-01-27 10:03:21 to 2017-01-27 10:04:20`

There are 5 entry within `2017-01-27 10:02:12` to `2017-01-27 10:03:11` for same `entity` `book` and `entityID` `18` it should be counted as one. And similarly for the rest of the rows there should be total 5 unique hits.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you’ll have to somehow “round down” the timestamps to the interval. So for an interval of a minute, that would simply mean you discard the seconds part - for other intervals, it’s going to need a little more math probably. If you want to group by an interval of 30 minutes, then you would have to “round down” `2017-01-27 10:02:12` to `2017-01-27 10:00` first, and `2017-01-27 10:37:45` would become `2017-01-27 10:30` ...

Comment: Give your expected output for interval say `1 minute`. Also your sample has every combination within a minute, Try widening the timeframes and give your expected output based on that.

Comment: As an aside, consider not storing the word 'type'

Comment: @CBroe I can't actually round down the timestamps because `2017-01-27 10:02:12` to `2017-01-27 10:03:11` would be considered a valid `1 minute time interval`. Time interval should be counted after the first record of the hit

Comment: @Utsav I'll do that, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Strawberry `type` is just for demonstration purposes only. In real case I have `book`, `author`, 'publisher', `book_category` etc.

Comment: _“Time interval should be counted after the first record of the hit”_ - well then you should probably get that first record timestamp first, so that you can then adjust your interval “boundaries” accordingly.

Comment: Do you only want it to take into account the timestamp of the very first record (for that user/id combination)? Or, in your second example, after those four records within a minute are found, do you need the “next” minute interval to start at `2017-01-27 10:03:27`, so that a next record with `2017-01-27 10:04:22` would be counted for that interval as well?

Comment: @CBroe yes I was thinking same. I need to get the first hit, get the boundary, check for entry in the same interval, count one unique hit, repeat... I've updated my question again. Can you please check again? Thank you

Comment: Do you need to do this directly in MySQL? Would definitively be easier if you could do this afterwards in a scripting language of your choice.

Comment: @CBroe Well, I know that I can do it using php but I am interested if there is any SQL only solution to my problem. And thank you very much for your time.